# Balancing memory usage in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm developing some network driver for Linux kernel. I've got several if-else conditions where I'm reallocating or freeing "skb" structures - and here is the place where I'm a bit confused. Regarding what do I do in those if-else - I got 2 kind of errors:

1. Calltrace because double free of skb and then kernel panic and reboot
2. Mem-leak because I don't free some skb

My question is - is there any kind of formal method for looking for mem-leaks or double-mem-free errors? I know that kernel uses memory poisoning after freeing some skb, but it don't tell me where is the bug.

Sorry, but I'm not allowed to share code of this driver.

Comment: try `valgrind` to look for mem-leaks

Comment: Are you sure that valgrind helps me with looking for mem-leaks in kernel space?

Comment: i missed that part. i think it wont work.. sorry

Comment: Is it possible to run most of the driver as a user space library, with just a bare bones set of kernel level code?

Comment: @steve: I'm afraid not. There are too many interactions with Linux kernel.

Answer (score 2):

kmemleak seems to be your friend. Please check if http://lwn.net/Articles/187193/ can help. This is worth a comment but my reputation is not 50 so can't add a comment to your question.